# How to add bootloader to ISO? Or, make ISO bootable?

Tags: linux, boot-loader, iso

How do I add a bootloader to a Linux ISO?

When I `isoinfo -d -i ...` I do not see the bootloader on one of the ISO's that I have; but on another ISO there is a bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to make a bootable ISO image:

`# mkisofs -r -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -o ../c.iso -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table .`

The `boot.cat` is required and so is the `isolinux.bin` as this indicates what is to be booted.

I also couldn't do this without root permissions.

Comment: Where do I get isolinux.bin and boot.cat?